# Why is there 2 viewport in D3D12Fullscreen sample? What is sceneviewport for?

Tags: directx, directx-12

In Microsoft's [DX12 sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/tree/master/Samples/Desktop/D3D12Fullscreen), there are [2 viewports](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Desktop/D3D12Fullscreen/src/D3D12Fullscreen.cpp#L38) (with 2 scissors, and 2 heap descriptors).

It seems that only the `postviewport` is used (at each resize, `LoadSizeDependentResources()` is called, which updates the `postviewport`).

So, in that case, what is the `sceneviewport` for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample uses two pass rendering. It first renders to an intermediate render target (using m_sceneViewport and m_sceneScissorRect) and then scales the intermediate render target to screen. Check OMSetRenderTargets calls. The "scale" takes place when the selected fullscreen mode dimensions are different from those of the intermediate render target.